# Which server exactly is run on port 80?

Tags: spring-boot, http, webserver, port

I have read that default port for http is 80. I have a few questions regarding this seemingly harmless statement.

(1) First of all, from my understanding, port is associated with an application, NOT a protocol and http is a protocol. So either my understanding is incorrect or this above statement implies web server by saying http and it is meant that web server runs on port 80.

(2) I am using spring boot and I have read that it uses an embedded tomcat which is again a webserver which complies with http protocol. Then how come it doesn't use port number 80. Why does it use 8080 port.

(3) Then if tomcat doesn't use port 80, then which web server exactly uses port number 80.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port 80 is the default for http connnections.
Port 443 is the default for https connections.

With port mapping, these 'default' ports can be changed to any port you wish to use, however, you will need to include the ":" sysmbol in the web address when attempting to access if it is not available on the defult port e.g `http://example.com:8080`.

Port mapping can be generally achieved by changing the listening port in your configurations or by setting some forwarding rules in your firewall.

Tomcat can indeed function on port 80, preferably 443, and 8080 is just the 'default' for development.

Answer (score 0):

Hypertext Transfer Protocol (**HTTP**) used in the World Wide Web.

HTTP Port-80 is used for HTTP (Hyper Text Transfer Protocol) connection by default. It is a popular and widely used port across the globe.